# How do I replace caps in URL in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a Google Analytics account for a site I now am helping with.  There is a history where no filters were applied and I would like to apply a filter to make all the URLs lowercase to match them up.

I see plenty on removing querystrings and such but nothing along the lines of replacing all uppercase chars with lowercase ones.

Is it possible?